# Asymptotic Behaviour Of A Bizarre Function

Tags: calculus, analysis

It is relatively easy to show that the asymptotic behaviour of $f(x)$, where
$$ f(x)= \left[\frac{x}{2}\right] + \left[\frac{x}{4}\right] + \left[\frac{x}{8}\right] + \left[\frac{x}{16}\right] + \cdots $$ is given by $$f(x)\sim x $$
( $[t]$ is the floor function)
However, I wonder what the second term in the asymptotic expansion of $f(x)$ is. So, if $$ f(x)=x-e(x)$$ where $e(x)$ is the error function and $$e(x)=o(x) $$ what is the asymptotic behaviour of $e(x)$? Can anyone find it and prove their result?

Edit: I have changed the sign of the error function in the definition since most of you were considering $x-f(x) $ as your error term and it is more natural anyways, since $f(x)$ is always slightly less than $x$. Also, I add on what I already can prove. For positive $x$, all the terms are positive. Hence, if we add up the first, say, $n$ terms, we will obtain a lower bound of f(x). The lowest possible value of these first $n$ terms would be:
$$ f(x)= \frac{x}{2} -1 + \frac{x}{4} -1 + \frac{x}{8} -1  + \cdots + \frac{x}{2^n} -1 = x\frac{2^{n}-1}{2^n} -n $$ Hence the maximum value of $e(x)$ is given by:
$$e(x) < x - (x\frac{2^{n}-1}{2^n} -n) = \frac{x}{2^n} + n  $$ We are free to chose any $n$ to make the bound as tight as possible. The bound has no maximum for large $n$, so taking its derivative and setting it equal to zero gives a value of $n$ for which the bound is tightest:
$$ 0 = 1 - x\frac{\ln 2}{2^n} $$ which yields
$$ n = \frac{\ln x + \ln ln 2}{\ln 2} $$ but we can only take integer $n$, so for optimising the bound we take the closest integer, resulting in:
$$ n = \frac{\ln x + \ln ln 2}{\ln 2} + t $$ where $ -\frac{1}{2} \leq t \leq \frac{1}{2} $ Hence the upper bound for $e(x)$ becomes
$$e(x)< \frac{\ln x}{\ln 2} + \frac{\ln ln 2}{\ln 2} + t + \frac{2^{-t}}{\ln 2} = O(\ln x) $$ I admit that Christian Blatter's proof can reach the same result and is simpler, but I just wanted to show what I had before posting the question.

Edit 2: Will Jagy, I've just realised the full consequences of your comment on the exponent of 2 in $[x]!$. It implies that $$f(x)=f([x]) $$ Hence it is sufficient to understand $f(x)$ for integer values!

Edit 3: The bound only holds for positive $x$. $$f(x)=-\infty$$ for all negative $x$

Edit 4: Will Jagy, indeed, for natural $x$, the error function $e(x)$ is equal to the amount of 1s in the binary expansion on $x$, or equivalently the sum of its digits in its binary expansion, as can be seen by writing $x$ as a sum of powers of two(binary).  That also easily proves the observation on $2^k -1$(all 1s in binary) and also proves the bound of $\frac{\ln x}{\ln 2}$ for the error function and explains why your "ties" increase by 1. Neat.

Comment: $f(1)=[1/2]+[1/4]+...=0+0+...=0\neq 1$. What am I missing?

Comment: It is not equal to x, but asmyptotic to x.

Comment: If $x$ is an integer, this is the exponent of $2$ in the prime factorization of $x!$ If $x$ is not an integer, it is still the exponent of $2$ in $\lfloor x \rfloor ! $

Comment: Interesting, Will Jagy, I hadn't thought of that, you are definitely right when x is an integer. How do you deduce your statement when x is not an integer?

Comment: Nothing changes if I take an integer $n$ and a disturbance $0 \leq \delta < 1,$ I still get $$ \lfloor (n+\delta) / 2^k \rfloor =  \lfloor n / 2^k \rfloor  $$ same for any denominator

Comment: Yes, I see. Thank you.

Comment: You really ought to be doing computer experiments on this yourself. You might get a conjecture that can be described explicitly, in any case you will learn things you do not currently know. Do integer $x$ up to 100, say.

Comment: Good idea, I will. No-one has asked me about how to prove the main term is x, so I put it out as a challenge for someone to show the asymptotic behaviour is indeed x.

Comment: The error term is probably of the form
$
e(x) \sim g(\{(\log x)/(\log 2)\}) \log x
$ (here $\{t\}=t-[t]$ is the fractional part), where $g$ is a fixed function defined on $[0,1]$ that has a fractal structure, satisfying some properties like $g(x+2^{-k})-g(x)=c_k$ for some constants $c_k$.

Comment: That sounds like in the right direction - I can prove that the error term is O(log x).

Comment: Computer simulations for integer x from 2 to 2047 shows an irregular function, always negative(this is clear), getting gradually further and further away from 0 and the x-axis. Dividing by log x due to suggestions by Greg Martin gives an irregular scatter which is bounded between 0 and -2. Does that bring any further ideas?

Comment: Your
$$ \color{magenta}{f(n) = n - s_2(n)},   $$
where $$ \color{magenta}{ s_2(n)} $$ is the number of $1$'s used when writing $n$ in binary (base two).

Answer (score 2):

ACTUAL VALUE: page 49 in [*Problems From The Book* by Titu Andreescu and Gabriel Dospinescu,](https://www.awesomemath.org/resources/xyz-press/problems-from-the-book.html) your
$$ \color{magenta}{f(n) = n - s_2(n)},   $$
where $$ \color{magenta}{ s_2(n)} $$ is the sum of the digits when writing $n$ in binary (base two).

EEDDIITT: this is better. I just said to print out when it had a new "champion" value of $n-f(n).$ This happened at $n=2^k - 1$ and nowhere else, so it should be provable, and give a very simple upper bound on $n-f(n).$ Here, the columns are just $$n, f(n), \frac{ \log (n-f(n))}{\log n}  $$

```
July 24 
         1         0    ratio  -nan
         3         1    ratio  0.6309297535714574
         7         4    ratio  0.5645750340535797
        15        11    ratio  0.511916049619631
        31        26    ratio  0.4686790650623293
        63        57    ratio  0.4324646885882443
       127       120    ratio  0.4017000405485778
       255       247    ratio  0.3752648695976044
       511       502    ratio  0.3523243043176422
      1023      1013    ratio  0.3322396410002739
      2047      2036    ratio  0.3145139299303313
      4095      4083    ratio  0.2987556451184895
      8191      8178    ratio  0.2846530655014742
     16383     16369    ratio  0.2719556335624028
     32767     32752    ratio  0.260460137547165
     65535     65519    ratio  0.2500003439683993
    131071    131054    ratio  0.2404391463380934
    262143    262125    ratio  0.2316625709103845
    524287    524268    ratio  0.2235751646663665
   1048575   1048555    ratio  0.2160964196103092
   2097151   2097130    ratio  0.2091579793649986
   4194303   4194281    ratio  0.2027014403799804
   8388607   8388584    ratio  0.1966766082557382
  16777215  16777191    ratio  0.1910401048812062
  33554431  33554406    ratio  0.1857542479104541
  67108863  67108837    ratio  0.1807861431549078
 134217727 134217700    ratio  0.1761069445946825
```

EEEEEEEEDDDDDDDDDDDDDIIIIIIIIIITTTTTTTTTT TOOOOOOO: This time I said to put a blank line before each new champion, but also printout when there is a tie, and put a column showing $n-f(n).$ Neat how the number of ties also increases by one. These numbers $n$ are just those written, in binary, with all $1$'s or a single $0$ and the rest $1$'s.

```
July 24 

         1         0         1    ratio  -nan
         2         1         1    ratio  0

         3         1         2    ratio  0.6309297535714574
         5         3         2    ratio  0.4306765580733931
         6         4         2    ratio  0.3868528072345416

         7         4         3    ratio  0.5645750340535797
        11         8         3    ratio  0.4581569099913262
        13        10         3    ratio  0.4283173410313947
        14        11         3    ratio  0.4162896638657992

        15        11         4    ratio  0.511916049619631
        23        19         4    ratio  0.4421294589150075
        27        23         4    ratio  0.4206198357143049
        29        25         4    ratio  0.4116936649208689
        30        26         4    ratio  0.4075900941810124

        31        26         5    ratio  0.4686790650623293
        47        42         5    ratio  0.4180197953240187
        55        50         5    ratio  0.4016231838083947
        59        54         5    ratio  0.3947083097518978
        61        56         5    ratio  0.3915074910131681
        62        57         5    ratio  0.3899649883623831

        63        57         6    ratio  0.4324646885882443
        95        89         6    ratio  0.3934580384754998
       111       105         6    ratio  0.380453971550872
       119       113         6    ratio  0.374913825058222
       123       117         6    ratio  0.3723380770372397
       125       119         6    ratio  0.3710942508531261
       126       120         6    ratio  0.370482842750058

       127       120         7    ratio  0.4017000405485778
       191       184         7    ratio  0.3704891178483478
       223       216         7    ratio  0.3598757781889093
       239       232         7    ratio  0.3553223956670001
       247       240         7    ratio  0.3531989451747938
       251       244         7    ratio  0.3521720609136298
       253       246         7    ratio  0.3516669399505442
       254       247         7    ratio  0.3514164136063703

       255       247         8    ratio  0.3752648695976044
       383       375         8    ratio  0.3496014306342006
       447       439         8    ratio  0.3407491316044483
       479       471         8    ratio  0.3369316947345405
       495       487         8    ratio  0.3351474224681802
       503       495         8    ratio  0.3342836426799187
       507       499         8    ratio  0.3338585322368201
       509       501         8    ratio  0.3336476351118843
       510       502         8    ratio  0.3335425965924355

       511       502         9    ratio  0.3523243043176422
       767       758         9    ratio  0.3307834314226946
       895       886         9    ratio  0.3232722619285337
       959       950         9    ratio  0.320020308124903
       991       982         9    ratio  0.3184976804594824
      1007       998         9    ratio  0.3177599550041736
      1015      1006         9    ratio  0.3173967362443336
      1019      1010         9    ratio  0.3172165077782897
      1021      1012         9    ratio  0.3171267351064634
      1022      1013         9    ratio  0.3170819337080672

      1023      1013        10    ratio  0.3322396410002739
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$
```

Here is some data that suggests strongly that $f(n)$ is especially small for $n=2^k - 1.$ We know it is especially large for $n=2^k.$ The columns are $$n, f(n), \frac{(\log\log n)^2 \; \log (n-f(n))}{\log n}  $$ where the final column goes (slowly) to zero if I do not square the $\log \log n.$ Put together, I do not see anything easy about this problem. Oh, I said to print out only if the final column increased, also started at $n=16$ because of the $\log \log n$ term.

```
July 24 
        16        15    ratio  0
        17        15    ratio  0.265332800824185
        18        16    ratio  0.2701579508922748
        19        16    ratio  0.4351346774238432
        21        18    ratio  0.4472847193117306
        22        19    ratio  0.4526359799754941
        23        19    ratio  0.5774041329942359
        27        23    ratio  0.5983057022187321
        29        25    ratio  0.6068624346250773
        30        26    ratio  0.6107689612012526
        31        26    ratio  0.7133623740665207
        47        42    ratio  0.7597110896324395
        55        50    ratio  0.7738851961291296
        59        54    ratio  0.7797112330030469
        61        56    ratio  0.7823751335295115
        62        57    ratio  0.7836511974611988
        63        57    ratio  0.8738068938311855
        95        89    ratio  0.9042421671519172
       111       105    ratio  0.9135550018438335
       119       113    ratio  0.9173768120296339
       123       117    ratio  0.9191224287940964
       125       119    ratio  0.9199581214962954
       126       120    ratio  0.9203671565212432
       127       120    ratio  0.999987254183505
       191       184    ratio  1.019273496066372
       223       216    ratio  1.025077239134491
       239       232    ratio  1.027436985627603
       247       240    ratio  1.028509646763625
       251       244    ratio  1.02902192292155
       253       246    ratio  1.029272352985746
       254       247    ratio  1.029396177111776
       255       247    ratio  1.1001662945016
       383       375    ratio  1.111490000372221
       447       439    ratio  1.114735255583041
       479       471    ratio  1.116021178046402
       495       487    ratio  1.116598002182193
       503       495    ratio  1.116871626038779
       507       499    ratio  1.117004934769511
       509       501    ratio  1.1170707362187
       510       502    ratio  1.117103426495222
       511       502    ratio  1.180412421713722
       767       758    ratio  1.185954790531906
       895       886    ratio  1.187314787399403
       959       950    ratio  1.187805264517309
       991       982    ratio  1.188013944695171
      1007       998    ratio  1.188110184124969
      1015      1006    ratio  1.188156393561383
      1019      1010    ratio  1.188179034244621
      1021      1012    ratio  1.188190240220727
      1022      1013    ratio  1.188195814819858
      1023      1013    ratio  1.245177571545955
      1535      1525    ratio  1.246467976554354
      2047      2036    ratio  1.29776436562204
      4095      4083    ratio  1.340656283419479
      8191      8178    ratio  1.37574625534843
     16383     16369    ratio  1.40449569749946
     32767     32752    ratio  1.428046437820909
     65535     65519    ratio  1.447300526904558
    131071    131054    ratio  1.462977901617132
    262143    262125    ratio  1.475658581170635
    524287    524268    ratio  1.485813922734257
   1048575   1048555    ratio  1.493830042476688
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$
```

Comment: Interesting, your observation on n=2^k-1. Thank you. Also, I would like to emphasize that this function is meant to be defined for all real x, not just natural numbers x, although I do understand it is simpler for natural numbers. And yes, I agree the question is not simple. In fact, I suspect, but cannot fully explain/prove, that a good approximation of f(x) would lead to a good approximation of the prime numbers.

Answer (score 2):

When $x<0$ then $f(x)=-\infty$, since an infinite number of terms is $=-1$.

It is easy to check that for all $n\geq0$ one has
$$\left\lfloor{x\over 2^n}\right\rfloor =\left\lfloor{\lfloor x\rfloor\over 2^n}\right\rfloor\ .\tag{1}$$
Therefore it is enough to consider integer $x\geq0$. Each such $x$ has a well defined binary representation
$$x=\sum_{k\geq0}b_k\>2^k,\qquad b_k\in\{0,1\}\ ,\tag{2}$$
whereby only finitely many $b_k$ are $\ne0$. Put $\sum_{k\geq0} b_k=: s(x)$.

We shall prove that for integer $x\geq0$ one has $$f(x)=x-s(x),\tag{3}$$ so that together with $(1)$ one obtains
$$f(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor -s\bigl(\lfloor x\rfloor\bigr)\qquad(x\in{\mathbb R}_{\geq0})\ .$$
One has $s(x)=O(\log x)$ for $x\to\infty$, but $(s(2^n)=1$ for all $n\geq0$.

*Proof* of $(3)$: From $(2)$ it follows that
$$\left\lfloor{x\over 2^n}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\sum_{k\geq0}b_k\>2^{k-n}\right\rfloor=\sum_{k\geq n}b_k\>2^{k-n}\ .$$
Therefore we obtain
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left\lfloor{x\over 2^n}\right\rfloor=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k\geq n}b_k\>2^{k-n}=\sum_{k\geq1}b_k\>2^k\sum_{n=1}^k 2^{-n}\ .$$
This can be rewritten as
$$f(x)=\sum_{k\geq1}b_k2^k(1-2^{-k})=\sum_{k\geq0}b_k\>2^k-\sum_{k\geq0}b_k\ ,$$
as claimed.

Comment: Nice and clear analysis, thanks. I believe it can be easily modified slightly for negative x. However, it only gives a bound for g(x), not its asymptotic behaviour, and, as I wrote in a comment already, I already have a proof that g(x)=O(log x).

Comment: $$ \color{magenta}{f(n) = n - s_2(n)},   $$
where $$ \color{magenta}{ s_2(n)} $$ is the sum of the digits when writing $n$ in binary (base two).